# Sorting large file of emails based on domain shows error

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting

I am trying to sort the 1 GB file containing emails based on the domains that they have using the following logic:

```
data = {}
emails = open('test','r',encoding='ascii',errors='ignore')
for email in emails.readlines():
    (user, domain) = email.split('@')
    data[domain] = email
    keys = data.keys()
    keys.sort()
print([data[x] for x in keys])
```

When I ran the file using Python 3.5 I got the following error:

```
    keys.sort()
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Kindly, let me know what to do to make it run successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `list` on the returned `dict_keys` object to cast it into a list which has the `list.sort` method:

```
keys = list(data.keys())
keys.sort()
```

Or simply call `sorted` directly on the `dict_keys` object to return a sorted list:

```
keys = sorted(data.keys())
```

On another note, you should dedent this part of the code so the sorting is not done every time a new key is added to the dict, but at the end of the loop.

Or simply apply `sorted` on the dict directly if you don't actually need the list of keys:

```
for email in emails.readlines():
    (user, domain) = email.split('@')
    data[domain] = email
print([v for _, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]))
```

Comment: `print([v for _, v in sorted(data.items(), lambda x: x[0])]) TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function` Getting this issue after applying your answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this as an answer because it will be easier to read. It doesn't answer your question directly, since it has already been answered, but is answering a problem you will notice the moment your code is able to be run.

**Problem:** Duplicated domains will result in only the last entry being saved. The line

```
data[domain] = email
```

overwrites what might have been written under that key before. What you want to do is substitute the line mentioned with this block:

```
try:
    data[domain].append(email)
except KeyError:
    data[domain] = [email]
```

That will create a list of users on same domain. If the key hasn't been found, a `KeyError` will be raised, and that is a signal that it is a new domain and you have to create another list. If the key has been found, we just append new email.

Comment: It is an excellent suggestion. I got the answer by combining both of your peoples answers... A bit of confused whose answer to select....:)

Comment: I think you should select the other answer, because it was the answer to what you wrote in question ;) But it's up to you, I guess...

Comment: No problem :) glad we managed to solve your problem together! #community